# Write logs to Unix box in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, unix, spring-boot, logging

I want to deploy my spring boot application to a unix server and write logs to a specific directory on the server. Right now, I am able to write logs to my a log file in my spring boot app but it is inside my project. So my project exists in Project/myApp and logs are written to Project/myApp/logs/myApp.log. If I wanted my logs to be written to a location on the server apps/development/serverlogs where would i specify that location?

In my application.properties I have only specified
`logging.file=logs/myApp` and it is creating the log file as planned. I would just prefer to have this outside my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the full path of the location of your choice as long as it exists and as long as the unix user that runs your project as the permission to access that location and write in it.

Change your settings in `logging.file=/.../.../apps/development/serverlogs` and if this path does not exist create `mkdir -p /.../.../apps/development/serverlogs`.

You might have to change the permissions on that folder depending on your `umask` and last but not least you might need to restart your application in order to have your changes at the config file level be reflected.